# Relative compactness of metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I know that in a metric space $X$ compactness, countable compactness and sequential compactness of a subspace $X'$ are equivalent using the definition of countable compactness as *every infinite subset of $X'$ has an accumulation point in* $X'$ and of sequential compactness as *every sequence in $X'$ has a subsequence converging to a point in* $X'$.

If we define relative countable compactness as *every infinite subset of $X'$ has an accumulation point in* $X$ and of relative sequential compactness as *every sequence in $X'$ has a subsequence converging to a point in* $X$, do I correctly understand if I desume, in a straightforward way by taking into account the properties of closed sets in a metric space, that in a metric space $X$ relative compactness, countable relative compactness and sequential relative compactness of a subspace $X'$ are equivalent?

$\infty$ thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already showed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/929524/4280) that $X'$ relatively compact implies $X'$ relatively countably compact. Also, if $X'$ is relatively compact, the $\overline{X'}$ is compact, and thus sequentially compact (this holds in particular in metric spaces, but also more broadly). So any sequence from $X'$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in $\overline{X'}$, so $X'$ is then relatively sequentially compact as well.

In any space, $X'$ relatively sequentially compact implies $X'$ relatively countably compact: any infinite subset $A$ of $X'$ contains some sequence with all different elements, which has a convergent subsequence to some $x \in X$, and this $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$.

If $X'$ is relatively countably compact, and $X$ is metric (first countable and $T_1$ will already do), let $(x_n)$ be a sequence from $X'$. If $A = \{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is finite, some value occurs an infinite number of times, and yields a convergent subsequence. So assume $A$ is infinite, so it has an accumulation point $p \in X$. Because $X$ is $T_1$, this means that every neighbourhood of $p$ intersects $A$ in infinitely many points. Pick $x_{n_1}$ in $B(p, 1)$, $x_{n_2}$ with $n_2 > n_1$ in $B(p, \frac{1}{2})$, and so on, by recursion. This defines a convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to $p$. So $X'$ is relatively countably compact.

If $X'$ is relatively countably compact, and $X$ is metric, then we do get that $X'$ is relatively compact (this is due to Hausdorff, IIRC). I cannot reconstruct a proof right away, but there is one [here](http://books.google.nl/books?id=R6UhqdtWirgC&pg=RA1-PA331&lpg=RA1-PA331&dq=%22relatively%20countably%20compact%22%20iff%20closure%20is%20countably%20compact%20for%20metric%20spaces&source=bl&ots=Q1PHuI8ZbV&sig=VbdoEnpdjTNAWwa9_Kj0nKDLuOo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=l64UVNeXH4zUPL72gdgD&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22relatively%20countably%20compact%22%20iff%20closure%20is%20countably%20compact%20for%20metric%20spaces&f=false), e.g. (but this involves Cauchy filters etc.)

It turns out that these notions are also equivalent in some topological vector spaces (spaces of the form $C_p(X)$ where $X$ is compact (Grothendieck), and weak topologicals on normed vector spaces (Eberlein-Smulian)), but these are a bit more involved, I think.

Comment: I heartily thank you!!! So doesn't countable compactness imply sequential compactness in general? For weak* topology? I wonder because my book seemed to me to mean that in this issue: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929630/relative-countable-weak-ast-compactness-and-sequences

Comment: No, there are even compact (and thus countably compact) spaces that are not sequentially compact, like $[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$ in the product topology, or the Čech-Stone compactification of the integers ($\beta\mathbb{N}$). So there is something to prove!

Comment: ...and the text calls it an "immediate consequence"...! $\aleph_1$ thanks!

Comment: It could be equivalent for weak*, but it's not equivalent in general. My functional analysis is somewhat rusty..

Comment: In http://math.stackexchange.com/a/27439/4280 example (i): the  unit ball in $\ell_\infty^\ast$ is weak*-compact but not weak*-sequentially compact. In the other answer there it is shown that $X$ separable will make it true, as then this unit ball is metrisable, and sequential compactness and compactness are equivalent again.

Comment: Thanks again! I've also thought to use the metrisability of the unit ball of $E^{\ast}$ to show that countable weak$^\ast$-compactness implies relative sequential weak$^\ast$-compactness if $E$ is separable, but that doesn't seem to work. To tell the truth I'm not even so convinced it's true, but, otherwise, I cannot figure how corollary 2 (here: http://librarum.org/book/10022/106 ) "immediately" derives from theorem 2' (here: http://librarum.org/book/10022/105 )...

Comment: Corollary 2 problem solved: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929630/relative-countable-weak-ast-compactness-and-sequences/932357#932357 . I heartily thank you again, Henno, for your answers!